# trying to concatenate missing } to invalid json object

Tags: python, json

i have a line in my json file that is missing a closing bracket ('}') at the end of a line.

sample input:

```
{"title_text": "Malformed JSON", "createdAt": "2020-10-17T02:56:51+0700", "text": "Some post content", "author": "ninja"
{"title_text": "Fourth title", "createdAt": "2020-10-17T02:56:51+0700", "text": "Some post content", "author": "star"}
```

the "Fourth title" json object adds to data, but I want to add a '}' to the end of the line "Malformed JSON" and append the complete json object to my data array.

however, i've tried running the code below and it appends everything but the Malformed JSON to the data array.

```
data = []
with open('../example.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except JSONDecodeError:
             if line and line.endswith(" "):
                data = data[len(line)-1].append("}")
                data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: what is input, what is expected & what error u r getting?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani the input (example.json) is the Malformed JSON and Fourth title json objects. i'm not getting any errors, its just that Malformed JSON isn't appending to my data array and i'm not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample you have provided doesn't end with a space.

```
import json
from json.decoder import JSONDecodeError
data = []
with open('./example.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except JSONDecodeError:
             # Can add other failure conditions as well
             if line and not line.endswith("}"): 
                line = line + "}"
                data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
import json

data = []
with open('../example.json', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            if line and not line.strip().endswith("}"):
                line = line.strip() + "}"
                data.append(line)
```

Your line 1 is end with '\n' , not ' '.